# Jquery response from php with javascript built-in

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this Javascript function that sends username and password to php file through jquery and then gets a response back to display text and then depending on if it was successful or not, it would display it in either green or red. (Green being successful, red - anything else):

```
function get() {
            $("#message").hide();
            $.post("login-exec", {
            login: form.login.value,
            password: form.password.value
            },
                function(output) {
                    if($.trim(output) == "Login Successful"){
                        document.getElementById("message").style.color = 'green';
                        $("#message").html(output).fadeIn(2000);
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById("message").style.color = 'red';
                        $("#message").html(output).fadeIn(2000);
                    }

                });
        }
```

I was wondering if I could do this logic with the style.color on the php file and then just send the output which would have the apropriate green, red and text response already. Like somehow include javascript in the response and then parse it out to run the javascript code as well as the message text.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the style color using css, as illustrated in http://jsfiddle.net/TLkMF/ .

If the PHP returns the json of the variable `output` in the fiddle, it should do what you want.

If you want to set the message text as well, then you can do so as illustrated in http://jsfiddle.net/TLkMF/1/

Comment: I agree that the PHP should return the response as JSON. But I would definitely avoid putting CSS information in there. Instead, return something like { "status": "success" } or { "status" : "failure" }. Then use that status value as a CSS class. If you ever decide that success messages should be blue instead, you only have to change the CSS declaration.